# Getting arabic string from NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7

I trying to make an app where the user enters a text then save it to the database but before that it will be added to NSMutableArray. The thing is when I log the array, it removes the encoding and shows the text like this:

```
\U0662\U0664.\U0660\U0665.\U0662\U0660\U0661\U0664 \U0660\U0662:\U0663\U0662 \U0635
```

Can someone help me and tell me how to re-encode the text to arabic?

EDIT : the text is not showing correctly neither in the log or the interface.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, these are unicode characters. Display them in a UILabel or even in the console and see just what the output is.

Comment: NSLog doesn't take the time to figure out your device's character set settings and logs most "extended" characters that way.  The data is still correct (if it ever was) and will display correctly in a UI element.  But note you will screw up the data if you ever do a string <-> byte array conversion without using the UTF8 character set.

Comment: (Also you can screw up the data if you attempt to use the result of `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", myArray]` for some reason.)

Comment: so what should I do ?

Comment: (And maybe read up on Unicode.)

Comment: http://unicode-table.com/en/#arabic

Answer (score 0):

Logging the array and logging the string is not the same thing and the string *will* display differently in the console depending on how you do it. That is, there is a difference between logging:

```
po yourArray
```

and

```
po [yourArray firstObject]
```

---

As long as the string displays correctly in your interface both before and after storing it in the database you should have nothing to worry about. The way the string is printed to the console when you log the contents of the array does not affect how it appears when you display it using a label in your UI.

Comment: Actually it doesn't display at all in the interface

Comment: @faisal60 - So, work backwards to the point of failure.  What operation corrupts the data??  (This is called "debugging".)

Comment: Well I did some debugging and no error found but when I get the string from the array it doesn't show it as it should but print \U0662\U0664.\U0660\U0665.\U0662\U0660\U0661\U0664 \U0660\U0662:\U0663\U0662 \U0635